# Split a vector list with M elements into 2 lists of N and M-N elements

Tags: r

I created a vector list, aa, with 50 elements. And I need to split aa into two vector lists called bb and cc. bb has the first 20 elements of aa while cc has the last 30 elements of aa. How do I do it?

Creation of original vector list

```
aa <- list (sample (1:50))
aa
#[[1]]
# [1] 29 30 39 45 17 11 43 14 24 34  3  1 28  2 21 23  6 31  5 27 44  7  4 46 49 22 33 38 50 36 15 48  8 16 25 42 13 41 47
#[40] 37 26 32 35  9 18 10 20 40 19 12
```

Sorry all, I know my question is really basic. Maybe it is because the question is too simple and the solution is thus not easily found from the internet.

Comment: Try with `split` `split(vector_list, rep(1:2, c(m, n)))`  where `m`, `n` are the lengths of the elements tthat should be in the split list

Comment: I do not know how to use split. So sorry =( OK I will try now, thank you so much

Comment: Tried it, does not work for me. I am unable to see how to derive list1 and list2 from your code using split(vector_list, rep(1:2, c(m, n))). Sorry I am really new to R

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: So `bb <- aa[[1]][1:20]` and `cc <- aa[[1]][21:50]` ?

Comment: Thanx Ronak, your answer solves my problem. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't a direct question answering this adding an answer. We can first subset the list using `[[` and then select individual elements in it with `[`.

```
bb <- aa[[1]][1:20]
cc <- aa[[1]][21:50]
```

We can also use `head` and `tail` to select first 20 and last 30 elements respectively.

```
bb <- head(aa[[1]], 20)
cc <- tail(aa[[1]], 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `vectors`

```
lst1 <-  split(aa[[1]], rep(1:2, c(20, 30)))
```

and extract the vector with `[[`

```
lst[[1]]
lst1[[2]]
```

It can be extended to any number of splits (i.e. generalized version) where we just need to change the `rep`